# Probability - Proving $3$ events are not independent.

Tags: probability, independence

> A fair die is thrown two times. We will consider the following events:
>
> $A:$  The die first shows an odd number.
>
> $B: $ The die second shows an odd number.
>
> $C:$ The die shows an odd number in both throws or the die shows an even number in both throws.
>
> Prove that  the events $A$, $B$, $C$ are *not* independent.

The first part of the question was asking for a proof that all pairs of the events are independent, which I easily gave by defining the sample space $\Omega$ and showing that $P(X \cap Y) = P(X)\cdot P(Y)$ for all pairs of events. But how do I go about proving dependence for the *three* events? Any hint would be much appreciated.

Comment: So you showed that $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B), P(A \cap C) = P(A)P(C)$ and so on for each pair of events from $A, B$ and $C$? Then there is only one thing left to do. What can you figure out about $P(A \cap B \cap C)$?

Comment: @Novice Can we define a new event $D = A \cap B$ with $P(D) = P(A \cap B)$ and show that $P(D \cap C) \neq P(D) \cdot P(C)?$

Comment: Yes, although I think it would be more proper to forget about relabeling using $D$ and simply show that $P(A \cap B \cap C) \neq P(A)P(B)P(C)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: How does the $P(C)$ change when conditioned on $B \cap C$? That is, given events $A$ and $B$, what is the probability of $C$ happening? How does this compare to the unconditioned probability of $C$ happening?

If these probabilities are not the same, then the events cannot be mutually independent.

Comment: Of particular note: When the two dice both show odd faces, then surely event $C$ occurs.  So $A\cap B\cap C=A\cap B$.  Add the fact that $\mathsf P(C)\lt 1$ ...